# Silverlight (2.0/3.0) Shape downloads

Tags: silverlight, download

Does anyone know of a place to download pre-built or defined silverlight (2.0/3.0) shapes?

Comment: What do you mean by shapes - are you looking for vector based "clip art" or predefined path data for something like a triangle?

Comment: Not really sure, mainly control containers. Something like a rect with rounded edges and gradient shading that can contain a bullet list or some other controls. 

I was wondering if someone might have created a gallery or example catalog of such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get a feel for Xaml - maybe these tutorials would help: http://silverlight.net/learn/videocat.aspx?cat=2#HDI2Controls

The site silverzine.com also has some good Xaml how-tos.  The specific instance you commented on, like a a rectangle with rounded edges and a bullet list could be constructed like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="4" Width="400" Height="300" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Border.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>

    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">
      <ListBox Height="200">

        <ListBox.Items>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="15" Fill="Black"/>
              <TextBlock Margin="10,4,0,0" Text="Item 1"/>
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="15" Fill="Black"/>
              <TextBlock Margin="10,4,0,0" Text="Item 2"/>
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="15" Fill="Black"/>
              <TextBlock Margin="10,4,0,0" Text="Item 3"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </ListBox.Items>
      </ListBox>
      <Button Margin="10" Content="Click Me!"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
```

To answer the question, I don't know of a site that has examples that the one you said you were looking for.  I think a good strategy would be to narrow down your search a bit and tackle one thing at a time.  Start with the border, then look around for gradients, etc.  Good luck!